# How to get specific information from an API into a variable?

Tags: php, curl

I have some output from an API:

```
{"id":"usr_3290ad77-a2d8-40da-9edf-21e624c23f27","username":"knuffelbeestje","displayName":"KnuffelBeestje","bio":"Working on a new worldǃ\nDC Hub is coming soon to community labsǃ","bioLinks":["https://steamcommunity.com/id/KnuffelBeestje","https://twitch.tv/knuffeldiertje"],"currentAvatarImageUrl":"https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/file/file_d66e4e65-6ce7-4321-8770-1c70840adfa9/1/file","currentAvatarThumbnailImageUrl":"https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/image/file_d66e4e65-6ce7-4321-8770-1c70840adfa9/1/256","tags":["show_social_rank","system_trust_basic","system_avatar_access","system_world_access","language_nld","language_eng"],"developerType":"none","last_login":"","last_platform":"standalonewindows","allowAvatarCopying":false,"isFriend":false,"friendKey":"","location":"","worldId":"offline","instanceId":"offline"}int(1) 1
```

How I got it:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/users/KnuffelBeestje/name? 
apiKey=JlE5Jldo5Jibnk5O5hTx6XVqsJu4WJ26');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Authorization: Basic PrivateKey']);
$apicontent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump(json_decode($apicontent, true));
```

(The API key is public, don't worry).
I want to save the "bio" into a variable in PHP, how can I do that?

Comment: `json_decode($apicontent, true)['bio']` ?

Comment: First you must fix the code, at the time of running it returns me:
{"error": {"message": "\" Credentials are missing \ "", "status_code": 401}}

Comment: @JoelJaime The code is working correctly. The "PrivateKey" just needs to be changed to an actual key in order for it to work. But I can't really show the key ;)

Comment: Hahahaha you're right, I don't know what happened to me asking you for that information :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is something like this

```php
$curl = curl_init('https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/users/KnuffelBeestje/name?apiKey=JlE5Jldo5Jibnk5O5hTx6XVqsJu4WJ26');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,[
    'Authorization: Basic PrivateKey'
]);
$apicontent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$content = json_decode($apicontent, true);
$id = $content['id'];
$username = $content['username'];
$bio = $content['bio'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function is returning an associative array. This means that you can append `['bio']` to it and get the value for the bio (or any other value of course). Then just save it in a variable like

`$bio = json_decode($apicontent, true)['bio'];`

Comment: json_decode will return associative array only if the assoc flag is on (the second parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/users/KnuffelBeestje/name? 
apiKey=JlE5Jldo5Jibnk5O5hTx6XVqsJu4WJ26');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Authorization: Basic PrivateKey']);
$apicontent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Passing true means we want an associative array
$data = json_decode($apicontent, true)

var_dump($data['bio']);
```

You can also use this as an object as it's JSON:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api.vrchat.cloud/api/1/users/KnuffelBeestje/name? 
apiKey=JlE5Jldo5Jibnk5O5hTx6XVqsJu4WJ26');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Authorization: Basic PrivateKey']);
$apicontent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Not passing true as the second param. We'll have an object.
$data = json_decode($apicontent)

var_dump($data->bio);
```